# Connect Micromax A100 with Eclipse

Tags: android

I want to know that I can connect micromax a100 with the eclipse for android development or not. From other community I found that for development purpose micromax device can not be used. Also I doesn't found any usb driver for that. So please help to come out that.

Comment: even i am facing same issue.... any luck from your side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research about the multiple company devices, I found that windows operating system require device driver. If your device has no driver then you can not use your device for development purpose in windows. While linux has some flexibility in that one. You can connect and use any company device for development purpose that I have tested and used. You have to modify only 51-android.rules file for you device. I answer my own question because this information become useful to many other community members that I think.

Comment: So Siddharth are you able to connect device on window for device debugging and have you try to debug Micromax A100 adn is it working?

Comment: I have tried but Micromax A100 can not use for debug purpose in windows but in Linux I use it for debugging purpose.

Comment: you mean to say you have tried in ubuntu? is there any driver required for the same?

Comment: No there is no driver requirement for the ubuntu.

Comment: thanx Siddharth.

Comment: can u please tell me where i will find the 51-android rules file...?

Comment: You have to look into /etc/udev/rules.d folder. In that you have to find usb specification file and add you device detail in it. that you found using "lsusb" command in terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this device but Eclipse doesn't care about this, your bridge between your Android phone and your PC is [`adb`](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html), a tool distributed with the Android SDK, and you should be able to develop and test an application with every Android device out there.

The only real problem are the drivers; the suggested platform for Android development is a Gnu/Linux distribution but many people still use Windows or Mac, with Windows you must have the right drivers for your device because otherwise you can't use it and you can't connect it to your PC. On a GNU/linux distribution you don't have this problems and the setup is much more easier.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I does not found any information about connecting device of micromax in android USB vender ids http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html. So I might have question that it is possible to use this device with android development.

Comment: @Siddharth you don't have specified your OS yet ...

Comment: Currently I was using windows XP. Also the platform does not matter for me. I also ready to shift in lynux. Basically I want to know that micromax device used for the android development debugging or not.

Comment: under linux you can use `lsusb` to get the numerical ID for your device, that list is just about the most popular brand, run `lsusb` an you should get something like `Bus 002 Device 007: ID 04e8:689e Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-S5670 [Galaxy Fit]` and you want the string that here says `04e8`, do the same for you device and follow the instrunctions on that page, don't forget to enable the USB debug and all the development options on your device.

Comment: I will try for that and I found any thing useful then I return back here. Thank you for spare time for me.

Comment: I want to know that if id found using above command, we can connect any company device with eclipse for debug purpose with linux os. And in window if we have device usb driver then we can connect it with eclipes.

Comment: @Siddharth that code identifies a manufacturer, so you are creting a rule for all the USB devices under linux from that brand, you can do the same for all the linux distributions, under Windows you only need to install the drivers.

Comment: so basically all the type of android supported devices can be used for debugging purpose in eclipse. In windows we must require a driver for that purpose. For above my conclusion answer me.